# How to append dataframes in a single excel sheet in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, append

I have to generate multiple data frames in a loop. How to generate a single output excel/CSV file comprising all the data frames in R?

Comment: Should the resulting Excel workbook contain one worksheet per data frame, or should all data frames be combined into a single worksheet? Does each data frame contain the same columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put all of your dataframes in a list and use the `openxlsx` package:

```
library(openxlsx)

openxlsx::write.xlsx(list_of_dataframes, "File Name.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
```

This will write out one Excel file, with a tab for each list object.

Example with `iris` and `mtcars`:

```
data(mtcars)
data(iris)

list_of_dataframes <- list(mtcars, iris)

openxlsx::write.xlsx(list_of_dataframes, "File Name.xlsx", row.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the loop, you can do the following:

```
final <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:n){
   
  # computations to generate data frame
  df <- ... 

  # bind the data frame to the final result
  final <- rbind(final, df)
}
```

This will combine all the data frames you generate within your loop into one large one, called `final`. Now to save `final` as a .csv:

```
readr::write_csv(final, path = "output.csv")
```